# Postfixのmyhostnameが反映されない

Tags: postfix

/etc/hostname の内容を、ドメイン名以外で運用しています。

メール送信のためPostfixをインストールし、設定ファイルmain.cfで
myhostname = mail.ドメイン名.com
としましたが、送信したメールには反映されず、/etc/hostnameの内容が
送信元アドレスとなってしまいます。

どの様に、修正すれば良いでしょうか？

＜追加情報＞
postconf -nの結果

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomaina, $mydomain
mydomain = ******.com
myhostname = mail.******.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $myhostname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP unknown
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

mail.logの内容です

```
$ cat /var/log/mail.log
Apr 14 12:20:26 Debian postfix/qmgr[595]: 91EBB1FC38: from=<user01@Debian>, size=335, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 14 12:20:26 Debian postfix/smtp[739]: 91EBB1FC38: to=<送信先@provider.ne.jp>, relay=mx.provider.ne.jp[219.111.22.333]:25, delay=327, delays=327/0.19/0.07/0.18, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host mx.provider.ne.jp[219.111.22.333] said: 450 4.1.8 <user01@Debian>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Apr 14 12:21:02 Debian postfix/pickup[594]: E5F4B1FC3A: uid=1000 from=<user01@Debian>
Apr 14 12:21:02 Debian postfix/cleanup[744]: E5F4B1FC3A: message-id=<20180414032102.E5F4B1FC3A@mail.******.com>
Apr 14 12:21:02 Debian postfix/qmgr[595]: E5F4B1FC3A: from=<user01@Debian>, size=333, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 14 12:21:03 Debian postfix/smtp[739]: E5F4B1FC3A: to=<送信先@provider.ne.jp>, relay=mx.provider.ne.jp[219.111.22.333]:25, delay=0.69, delays=0.17/0.01/0.06/0.45, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host mx.provider.ne.jp[219.111.22.333] said: 450 4.1.8 <user01@Debian>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: 設定変更後、postfixのプロセスは再起動しましたか？

Comment: はい、再起動しました。また、/etc/hostnameをドメイン名に変更するとメールは配信されますが、/etc/hostnameをDebianなどにしておくと、Sender address rejected: Domain not found　でメールは配信されません

Comment: メールの発信に利用している MUA の種類、コマンドラインの MUA であれば実際のコマンドラインを示してください。Postfix (のデフォルト設定で)は MUA が指定した(エンベロープ)送信者アドレスを上書きしませんよ。

Comment: Postfixとmailuitlsをインストールしています。　Debianのターミナルから、$ mail 相手メールアドレス -s Subject 本文  ctrl+Dでメールを送信しています。

Comment: 追加情報はコメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください。また、postconf -n の実行結果とメールを送信したときの/var/log/maillogの内容を追記してください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfixはメールアドレスがドメインなしの場合にドメインを付加します。また、ドメイン部に"."が含まれない場合にも付加を行いますがこれは設定で無効にされています。

myhostnameを変更しても変化がないということはPostfixが受け取った時点でドメインが付加されているものと思われます。

Postfixではなく送信側で付加されているアドレスをどうにかするか、Postfixでどうにかしたいならカノニカルアドレスマッピングで書き換えを行うことができます。

参考 [Postfixアドレス書き換え](http://www.postfix-jp.info/trans-2.3/jhtml/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html)